# CSS media print table not align margin auto

Tags: html, css, printing, margin

I have a page where I need to center a table when I print. But when I put the margin auto table, the alignment is incorrect, it is further to the right than to the left.

RED: Is Body

Green: Is Table

Black: Is TD

```
table {
    page-break-after:always !important;
    display:table !important;
    margin:auto !important;
}
```

[image: Error display]

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the 'margin:auto;' not to work, but you can use width and margin to make sure it prints fine:

```
table {
    page-break-after:always !important;
    display:table !important;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the vertical and horizontal margins separately?

```
table {
    page-break-after:always !important;
    display:table !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```